# Logit summary renaming some categorical variables in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

when i ran `glm` function in R and checked its output, some categorical variables have expected Variable name attached with categories *VarNameLevelName*
but for some other variable are showing as *VarName1 VarName2* instead of ***VarNameLevelName***
 (whose value i checked with levels command and are not as expected)

example:

```
levels(CatvarP)
```

"X" "Y" "Z"

```
levels(CatvarQ)
```

"A" "B" "C"

```
mod <- glm(y ~ CatvarP+CatvarQ,data, family=binomial)  

mod$coefficients
```

CatvarPX CatvarPY **CatvarQ1 CatvarQ2**

> Note: it should be **CatvarQA CatvarQB**, right!!!

Sorry I can not reproduce the error with sample data nor i can share the data  but any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you use `tidy` from (`broom`) you can transform the output of your regression into a data frame. Maybe you can explore the structure of that data frame and check what is happening to your estimates.

Comment: just to add I am not running with default contrast in R and not with all levels (something like  `glm(y ~ 1)`)